# Custom REST Routing in CakePHP

Tags: rest, cakephp, routes, cakephp-2.0

I'm using CakePHP and I want to add custom routing.
For example, I want to POST to http://website.com/rest_events/search_event.json and get a list of results in JSON, but I am getting a 301 status code back, if I do GET request everything is fine, but I need POST. In route.php I have this:

```
     Router::connect(
        'rest_events/search_event',
         array(
            'controller' => 'rest_events',
            'action' => 'search_event',
            '[method]' => 'POST'
         )
     );

     Router::mapResources('rest_events');
     Router::parseExtensions('json', 'xml', 'csv', 'pdf');
```

Do you have any idea what can be the problem?
Thank you in advance!

Comment: Why is there a space after the slash? And what's up with this curly quote, that should result in a fatal parsing error? ps, please always mention your exact CakePHP version!

Comment: Sorry, i made this errors while i was typing the question, my code does not consist this errors. I am using version 2.0.